# Sharepoint REST API - AttachmentFiles from a collection of List Items

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to retrieve items from a Custom List in SharePoint 2013 along with any files that have been attached to those list items in one REST API call.

So, if I do this:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Connect_Contribution')/items?$filter=&$top=100&$expand=AttachmentFiles&$orderby=Created%20desc
```

I get a really nice response with one object per list item called AttachmentFiles that contains a results array that contains any document that has been uploaded to that list item (i.e. `AttachmentFiles.results[0] = {FileName: "bla bla", ServerRelativeUrl: "blah blah"}`).  Beautiful.

But of course, I want to limit the things that come back from this and I want to expand some other fields, so I really want to do this (add a $select portion):

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Connect_Contribution')/items?$filter=&$top=100&$select=Id,AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles&$orderby=Created%20desc
```

I get the error:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

Playing with the select a bit I can get results without an error, but not the results I want (remove `$select` reference to AttachmentFiles):

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Connect_Contribution')/items?$filter=&$top=100&$select=Id&$expand=AttachmentFiles&$orderby=Created%20desc
```

This returns a result, but now that I've specified a `$select=Id`, I ONLY get Id's and no AttachmentFiles object.

So, does the AttachmentFiles object have a special name or something that I need in the SELECT statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT -- RE: 2013 _api/ (my original answer pertained only to listdata.svc, which has been generally replaced by _api in 2013)

The following URL uses what you were looking for and seems to work just fine on O365

```
/getByTitle('<ListName>')/items?$filter=substringof('Item', Title)
    &$select=AttachmentFiles,Title&$expand=AttachmentFiles&$top=4&$orderby=Title"
```

Your second example URL also seems to work on my O365 site without error even though the filter criteria is empty -- your list does have attachments enabled?

---

The below applies to listdata.svc in _vti_bin for 2010 and 2013:

Use something like `...$select=...,Attachments,...&$expand=Attachments...`

Then (if you're using JSON) you'll get an array of attachment items with each list item (attachment array may be empty) you can access with `data.d.results[i].Attachments.results`

Without knowing exactly how you want to use the attachment info -- you can use this array to construct the actual attachment URLs like:

```
"/Lists/<listName>/Attachments/" + data.d.results[i].Id + "/" + 
 data.d.results[i].Attachments.results[k].Name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'm afraid that your suggestion doesn't work - and yes, I'm getting JSON Results and doing stuff with them.

When I put the following in:_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Connect_Contribution')/items?$select=Attachments&$expand=Attachments

I get the following error:
The field or property 'Attachments' does not exist.

Also, Attachments is a True/False field.  AttachmentFiles is the file collection array.

Comment: @skrile that's interesting -- I have something like this running in production on a 2010 server (using _vti_bin of course) and it calculates URLs as part of a view model to display them as links on a page. I checked my O365 site (using _api) and it seemed to work the same way this morning... I'll give it another look later though.

Comment: Progress:  If I use the listdata.svc, I can get what I'm looking for.

_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Connect_Contribution?$select=Attachments,CreatedBy/Name,CreatedBy/Account&$expand=Attachments,CreatedBy&$top=30

This of course isn't the best solution in that it is relying on the old way of doing things, but it does give me what I'm looking for.

Comment: So, this works:

 $.ajax({
    url: "<YOUR SHAREPOINT COLLECTION HERE>" +
        "_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Connect_Contribution?" +
"$select=Id,Attachments,Contributor/Name,Contributor/Account,ConnectId/Id,ConnectId/MeetingDate&" +
 "$expand=Attachments,Contributor,ConnectId&$top=50&$orderby=ConnectId/MeetingDate desc",
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        //if there is data
        if (data.d.results) {
           //do something with data
}}});

Comment: @skrile modified original answer -- your queries work on my O365 site... are you in an on premises environment?

Comment: Yes - it's a corporate installation.  When @Jon-o say "your queries work" which query are you referring to?

Comment: @skrile your second URL in your original question works on a custom list in my O365 site; which leads me to think the the issue is something specific to the list/fields you're working with or, perhaps, an underlying system issue since fixed on O365 (but I would be surprised if it were that). Try loading up a custom list with a thousand items or so from a spreadsheet and build up to your current scenario (with the multiple lookups) and check at what point the call fails

Comment: So, what I might be dealing with is a version problem.  I know we haven't put SP 1 on yet, so maybe these are just problems that go away if we have the latest release of SP.  Sigh, good times.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, although I want to make sure people know two things:

1.  The _api/web $expand statement DOES NOT WORK on my company's installation of SP 2013 so I cannot confirm the poster's solution works other than to accept their word for it.

2.  Using the listdata.svc service DOES WORK, although the results are a bit different then what the api/web service returns.

Comment: What about for a particular list item?